# When did "-tile" and "-sile" (in missile and volatile) become "-tl" (or "tahyl")?

Tags: pronunciation

The dictionary states as follows:

[vol-uh-tl, -til or, esp. British, -tahyl]

*Especially* British? Hmm.

Don't kill me: I've never heard the following lyrics actually performed; I've only read them; they're from one of the (presumably many) English translations of  the German original of the chorus in *The Czardas Princess* by Emmerich Kalman (who was Hungarian, but that's neither here nor there, I suppose):

> How can the truth be learned
>   Where Woman is concerned?
>   You call us full of ***guile***,
>   Capricious, ***volatile***.
>   Oh, why was Woman born?
>   To drive us mad, mad, mad, mad,
>   Mad with
>   Her sweetness,
>   Her devilry and scorn.

"Guile" obviously rhymes with "volatile" here, from which one could safely assume that the translation is ... uh ... *especially* ... British.

My question is where and when did the shift happen? Did the Yankees begin to slur the vowel, or did the Brits resolve not to elide it anymore - and when?

Comment: For what it's worth, most people where I live in Canada pronounce it in the...uh...especially British way.

Comment: @Anonym: ))))))!!!

Comment: Actually in the UK both ways of saying the word volatile are used.

Comment: @rkchl: Which version would Onslow "Keeping up Appearances" use?

Comment: :D trying to think back to his accent, I'm thinking -tahyl ?

Comment: Are you specifically asking about volatile or other words as well (missile is mentioned in the title, but not the body).  If you're talking words in general, Americans are somewhat mixed and shifting on the -ile ending.  infantile and reconcile (-tahyl) are some counter examples.  Textile went from -til to -tahyl in the last century.

Comment: @Dusty: "reconcile" is a verb, which is a whole separate can of worms. Thank you for the textile-last-century bit. I had no idea.

Comment: [Walker's Pronouncing Dictionary of the English Language](https://archive.org/stream/walkerspronounc00unkngoog) (London, 1828) says that *volatile* and *textile* ended the same way as *lentil*.

Comment: @PeterShor: Good one, thanks. Why aren't you posting it as an answer?

Comment: I didn't think it was a sufficient answer.

Answer (score 2):

[Walker's Pronouncing Dictionary of the English Language](https://archive.org/details/walkerspronounc00unkngoog) (London, 1828) says that *volatile* and *textile* end the same way as *lentil*.

[The Student's English Dictionary](https://books.google.com/books?id=mOsIAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA795&dq=textile+pronunciation&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiPuoelsLfKAhXK1h4KHdZTDC44ChDoAQg0MAU#v=onepage&q=text&f=false) (London, 1865), by Ogilvie, says that *textile* and *volatile* end the same way as *file*.

So it looks like the Brits stopped eliding it some time in the 19th century. (I'm sure that it happened quite gradually; you shouldn't take either of these dictionary's dates as endpoints of the process.)